# topic name inside the callback

Tags: ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use callback (python) like:

```
def callback(self,data):
    print data
    topic = data._connection_header['topic']
```

this call back is called for more than one subscriber alternatively. I am interested to know which topic is currently calling the callback. I use `data._connection_header['topic']` to get the name of the topic. I don't know for some topics I get their name but for some not. Like when callback is invoked for topic `/scan` I get error like:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1362483495.362445] bad callback: <bound method Generator.callback of <__main__.Generator object at 0x31435d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 678, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/my_workspace/my_pkg/src/callback.py", line 21, in callback
    topic = data._connection_header['topic']
KeyError: 'topic'
```

Any Idea? Or is there any other solution for knowing which topic is calling the callback? thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57095/topic-name-inside-the-callback/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2014-07-10**:
I just tried this out and the only keys I get are ['message_definition', 'latching', 'md5sum', 'type', 'callerid'].  I'm going to have to put the topic information into a text field because topic doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is no guarantee that the connection header you're trying to use will have a topic, however, you can work around this by passing the topic name to the callback function as an argument when you set up the subscriber.

For example:

```
def callback(self, data, topic):
    # do something with the topic
    print data
```

and then when you hook up your subscriber, do it like this:

```
rospy.Subscriber(my_topic, My_data_type, callback=callback_odom, callback_args=my_topic)
```

For some reason, passing it as a lambda function, i.e.:

```
rospy.Subscriber(my_topic, My_data_type, lambda top: callback_odom(top, my_topic))
```

doesn't work.

---

Originally posted by [CatherineH](https://answers.ros.org/users/22373/catherineh/) with karma: 248 on 2015-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-06-15**:
The answer here has the C++ equivalent (more complicated using boost::bind) http://answers.ros.org/question/63991/how-to-make-callback-function-called-by-several-subscriber/

**Comment by [afar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32894/afar/) on 2020-10-13**:
This is very handy in ROS1 and I always use it.
It seems this "callback_argsis"  is not available in ROS2 in "create_publisher" method.
Do you have any opinion on this?